# Keyboard is not open again in the Compose AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an AlertDialog in compose that includes a TextField. When the AlertDialog is opened the keyboard is closed and after that, I focused on the TextFied. Now the keyboard is opened and I close it by clicking on the Done button or arrow down button device in navigationBar but still, TextField is focused. the issue is here, now if I click on the TextField the keyboard is not opened again.

```
AlertDialog(
            modifier = modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            containerColor = Color.White,
            onDismissRequest = { },
            properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
            text = {
                Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(8.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        TitleText(
            text = stringResource(R.string.now_schedule),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
        )
        LightContentText(
            text = stringResource(R.string.you_can_search_course_apply_course_and_find_scholarship_for_abroad_studies),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline
        )
        CoralBasicTextField(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(maxHeight.div(3)),
            value = descriptionValue,
            updateTextValue = {
                setDescriptionValue(it)
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart,
            textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
            placeholder = stringResource(R.string.description)
        )
    }
            },
            dismissButton = {},
            confirmButton = {
                Row(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    LightContentText(
                        modifier = modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .clickable { onShowDoneDialog(false, false) },
                        text = stringResource(R.string.cancel),
                        style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                            fontSize = 14.sp
                        )
                    )
                    CoralButton(
                        modifier = modifier.weight(1f),
                        onClick = {
                            onShowDoneDialog(false, true)
                        }) {
                        MediumContentText(
                            text = stringResource(R.string.save),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/311437241) in Jetpack Compose that was already fixed in the latest library version.
Make sure that you are using the latest Jetpack Compose UI dependency V`1.6.0-rc01`:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.0-rc01"
```

---

If you want to clear the focus of a TextField, you can do so by:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

TextField(
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
    //...
)

focusManager.clearFocus()  // call in your onDone keyboard callback or in BackHandler
```

Comment: It's not working. when the keyboard closes, the TextField is still focused and doesn't clear focus

Comment: You did not state in your question that you want to clear the focus. With the code in my answer, the keyboard should open again when you click the `TextField`, even though the focus is not cleared. Also check your compose ui dependency.

Comment: You are right. the issue is related to the library version. there is no need to initial focusRequester if I update the library

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Then I will edit my answer and remove that code.